# Unexpected character error for quotes

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting errors like `Unexpected character '“'` (complete list of errors show below) with following code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace Chapter1
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void ThreadMethod()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(“ThreadProc: {0}”, i);
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
            t.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(“Main thread: Do some work.”);
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
            t.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Error   1   Unexpected character '“'
Error   2   Unexpected character '”'
Error   3   Unexpected character '“'
Error   4   Unexpected character '”'
Error   5   Invalid expression term ''
Error   6   ) expected
Error   7   ; expected
Error   8   Invalid expression term ''
Error   9   Invalid expression term ','
Error   10  ; expected
Error   11  ; expected
Error   12  Invalid expression term ')'
Error   13  ; expected
Error   14  Invalid expression term ''
Error   15  ) expected
Error   16  Invalid expression term ':'
Error   17  ; expected  
Error   18  ; expected
Error   19  ; expected
Error   20  Invalid expression term ''
Error   21  Identifier expected
Error   22  Invalid expression term ')'
Error   23  ; expected
```

Comment: Just use normal double quotes: `"`.

Comment: I think you should grab a beginner's book of c# and start with simple programs, before jumping to threads. threading is not easy if you don't even know the basics.

Comment: It looks like you copied this from some document, or from a website that does not format code correctly.  As a result, double-quotes have been translated into the special "66" and "99".  Be wary of this when you are copying code samples.

Comment: He said he is a new Programmer , and honestly said his problem . Why peoples down-voted him ? Kindly help him , PLEASE !!!

Comment: Aww I wish I was able to answer in a matter of seconds. Oh well, guess I missed out on the nice votes. (Should I go for a pundit). Also, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try to look before you ask here next time.

Answer (score 8):

**Problem :** you are using invalid quotes `“` to enclose the String in `Console.WriteLine()` method as below:

```
Console.WriteLine(“ThreadProc: {0}”, i);
```

and here

```
Console.WriteLine(“Main thread: Do some work.”);
```

**Solution :** you need to use proper double quotes `"` to enclose the String as below:

```
Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc: {0}", i);
```

and also

```
 Console.WriteLine("Main thread: Do some work.");
```

**Complete Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace Chapter1
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void ThreadMethod()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc: {0}", i);
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
            t.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Main thread: Do some work.");
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
            t.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your quotes are wrong should be regular double-quote instead of fancy one.

Likely caused by copy-paste of code through some editor that "prettifies" text (i.e. MS Word).

Answer (score 4):

You're using non-standard quotation marks... `”` and `”`. Use regular quotation marks, `"`.

Answer (score 2):

The curly quotes you are using are called "smart quotes". <strike>The compiler only deals with standard "dumb quotes."</strike> The compiler sees "dumb quotes" as a valid way to express a string, not smart quotes.

```
Console.WriteLine(“Hello!”); // compile-time error
Console.WriteLine("Hello!"); // ok 
string str = "Hello”";       // all right
char curlyQuote = '”';       // fine
```

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs):

> Curved and straight quotes are also sometimes referred to as smart
>   quotes (“…”) and dumb quotes ("…") respectively; **these names are in
>   reference to the name of a function found in several word processors
>   that automatically converts straight quotes typed by the user into
>   curved quotes**. This function, known as "educating quotes", was
>   developed for systems that lack separate open- and close-quote
>   keyboard keys.

**Side note**: You most likely copied & pasted from a PDF version of the book *Exam Ref 70-483*. (Your code was an example in the book.) If you really want to learn the material, type it by hand rather than paste it right into VS or whatever IDE/text editor you're using.